# Select2 search does not work with JSON File

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2, if I add data with option tag, **search** system works successfully but I imported **with JSON**, it's not working.

HTML

```
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<div id="banner-message">
<select id="allowedCategories" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

JS

```
// Create countries dropdown
        $('#allowedCategories').select2({
            placeholder: 'Select allowed categories',
            selectOnClose: false,
            tags: false,
            tokenSeparators: [',', ' '],
            ajax: {
                dataType : "json",
                url      : "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/614ef51eaa02be1d444e64fd",
            },
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fz3Lwmvp/

[image]

Clickable, writeable but there is no filtration

Answer (score 0):

Select2 will call your ajax URL to search data. In your case, it calls to `https://api.jsonbin.io/b/614ef51eaa02be1d444e64fd?term=baby&_type=query&q=baby`

You can see the requests in the below image.

[image: Select2 call to json file]

> Select2 will issue a request to the specified URL when the user opens
> the control (unless there is a minimumInputLength set as a Select2
> option), and again every time the user types in the search box. By
> default, it will send the following as query string parameters:

And this is the select2 document, https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#request-parameters

So you have to modify your JSON/API to let it can search data. Or you should get the data from JSON and use it to build `option` tag to let the normal filter works.

Answer (score 0):

no filter in your api json to return specific response, test with other api